# SSRS parameter error, error occured during local report processing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

SSRS shows parameter error with 0x80040e21 message, Command parameter[1] '' is invalid.

Currently building a report with SSRS connected to Oracle SQL database with OLEDB. I have two datasets running in the report. One dataset for the selections of choice in parameters, and second dataset showing the requested report on the selected parameter. But using this parameter on the second dataset, raises `Command parameter[1] '' is invalid.`

Dataset 1

```
select Description, GroupID from tblGroups where GroupID is not null
```

Dataset 2

```
select 
    ID
    , Name
    , GroupID
    , Date
    from tblABC
where 
 Date >   TO_DATE( '01-01-2020','DD-MM-YYYY')  
 and GroupID =  :GID
```

The parameters are binded correctly, and the properties of parameter in SSRS is of integer, and the datatype for the GroupID column is number. Both queries function well in oracle sql developer, accepting a number as parameter, or selecting through subqueries. The issue seems to be around SSRS with no clear error information.

Comment: I assume `GID` is the name of your SSRS parameter, that's what it should be. Also, using SQL Server the name is case sensitive, I'm not sure if it is in Oracle but worth just making sure it is exactly the same anyway

Comment: Yes ```GID``` is the name of the parameter, and is binded to the correct queried parameter. The same query works well in sql, but not in SSRS, there are no issues with case sensitivity